# Proving $(A \cap (A - B)') = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Smullyan's *A Beginner's Guide to Mathematical Logic*:

> By the method of indexing, prove that the following equations are valid.
> $$(A \cap (A - B)') = \emptyset$$

This is what I get:

$A = \{1,2\},  B = \{1,3\}$  therefore $A' = \{3,4\}$ and $B' = \{2,4\}$. So
$A - B = A \cap B' = \{2\}$.  Therefore $(A-B)' = \{1,3,4\}$, and
$A \cap (A-B)' = \{1\}$

Comment: Yes, by your example the equation is not true. Maybe an error, or unspecified extra context?

Comment: Your $A'$ suggests the universe is $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Is that given or is it something you didn't include in your example?

Comment: That is, in more familiar terms, $A \cap (A - B)' = A \cap B$; which of course is correct.

Comment: @EricTowers, $1 \equiv A \cap B$, $2 \equiv A \cap B'$, $3 \equiv A' \cap B$, and $4 \equiv A' \cap B'$.